# C# Code digger executable / class library project not works

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library

I am using vs 2012 and new to code digger, when i click on `Generate Inputs /Outputs Tables`

Code diggers show error message as,

> Code Digger is only supported for Portable Libraries. Please transfer
>   your code into a Portable Library and go to the settings to disable
>   this limitations.

So what should be my action here,
1. Should I convert my existing projects to Portable Library? Which I think not the good practice.
2. From where can i disable this limitations, it says settings? Where can i find this setting?
3. Is Code digger with VS 2012 really supports the normal class library/project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ideally** Code Digger was not designed to run on non-portable class libraries. See this link:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fb5badda-4ea3-4314-a723-a1975cbdabb4

That being said, you can do this under Advanced Options:
If you are ready to run Code Digger on code that doesn't sit in Portable Class Libraries, then you can go to [Tools - Options...], select [Pex, General] and under [Code Digger] set [DisableCodeDiggerPortableClassLibraryRestriction] to True.

[image]